# access the contents of a sharepoint list and update it

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

My problem is how to access the contents of a sharepoint list and update 
the contents by a button "Save" of another list that it have the same field.
I'm working in sharepoint online using JavaScript.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using the client side object model or CSOM from SharePoint Online, you can retrieve the details of a list item and create a new list item.

Basically, you would use at least two rountrips to the server from. First, you want to use the JavaScript library provided with SharePoint to get the SharePoint context, send an asynchronous query to SharePoint Online Web Services for the list item details, and process the results in a JavaScript callback function. Then you'd basically repeat the same to write the results to another list.

Take a look at the reference code for [List Item Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks) in How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code.

Comment: Firslty, I want to thank you but this article taked reference code with C# and I want to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: I've updated the link with the JavaScript version. Sorry for the mistake.